# How to calculate pairwise distances among all subjects in a matrix in Python

Tags: python

I have a feature matrix, where the subjects are in rows and features in columns. I want to calculate the pairwise distance (e.g. mean absolute distance) among all subjects (rows). What is the simplest and fastest way to do it?

Let the features be a matrix of size (100, 200).

```
features = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 1, (100,200)))
```

Desired outputs:

- Distance data frame: similar to below

  ```
  subject1 subject2 distance

  0        1        0.124 

  0        2        0.453
  ...
  ```
- Adjacency Matrix: My final purpose is to create Adjacency Matrix from calculated distances.

Comment: What is absolute distance?  What do you mean by pairwise distance?

Comment: Each subject is represented by a vector which corresponds to row in the feature matrix. By pairwise distance, I mean distance between two subjects. Absolute distance is the sum of element-wise differences of two vectors, i.e. $\sum{x^{(1)}_i - x^{(2)}_i}$, if divided by n it becomes mean absolute distance. I want to calculate the distance among all subjects (rows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure this is exactly what you want, but wanted to post as I think parts will be used for the solution,

I use [pairwise_distance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html) from sklearn, and then [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to shape the output to your desired format, so

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

features = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 1, (100,200)))
```

and create distances with

```
distances = pd.DataFrame( pairwise_distances(features) )
distances['subject'] = distances.index

distances.melt(id_vars=['subject'])
```

Which will return

```
      subject variable     value
0           0        0  0.000000
1           1        0  5.479917
2           2        0  5.696208
3           3        0  5.889866
4           4        0  5.851760
...       ...      ...       ...
9995       95       99  5.571289
9996       96       99  5.588377
9997       97       99  5.794598
9998       98       99  6.021844
9999       99       99  0.000000
```

Duplicates/Zeros are still part of that, it is the whole sjabang!

Comment: Thanks @user3184950, this is exactly what I want. The default distance metric is 'euclidean'. For absolute distance, "manhattan" is defined. I used  ´distances = pd.DataFrame(pairwise_distances(features, metric="manhattan"))´